# Producing JaCoCo unit test coverage report in XML using Android Gradle Plugin

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, code-coverage

I'm trying to add test coverage reporting to an Android app project. The app is written in Kotlin and build with Gradle (Groovy variant) into 5 flavors.

The following Gradle plugins are used:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
```

I've been following a lot of different guides on integrating JaCoCo, but none of them worked for me. A minor breakthrough happened when I realized that the Android gradle plugin has (criminally underdocumented) builtin support for generating JaCoCo `.exec` files by adding `enableUnitTestCoverage true` into `buildTypes { debug { ... } }`.

However, I need the report in XML format for publishing the results into GitHub PRs using [this Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/jacoco-report).

I've also found that including `testCoverageEnabled` in the same block above adds the Gradle task `create${flavor}CoverageReport` which seems to do what I'm looking for

```
createProdMainNetDebugCoverageReport - Creates test coverage reports for the prodMainNetDebug variant.
```

However, running this task complains that no device is connected:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:connectedProdMainNetDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!
```

How can I get a code coverage report for all *unit tests* in XML format using the Android Gradle Plugin? Or would I be better served by configuring it more manually? How would I avoid my configuration conflicting with the existing one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The other answer by @Fah helped be find the [solution](https://github.com/Concordium/concordium-reference-wallet-android/pull/200/files) that I ended up using. Also, there are great many posts around the web describing how people have integrated JaCoCo into their projects in various ways.

The solutions are mostly similar, but all a little different because they fit into different projects. And none of them worked directly for my setup. So while the problem really isn't very complicated, it's important to understand how the pieces fit together in order to make the right adjustments for your particular project. The following is my attempt as a Gradle noob at explaining all these pieces from what I've gathered while investigating this:

Fundamentally, the solution breaks down to

1. Enable coverage instrumentation/collection in the unit test runner.
2. Define one or more Gradle tasks of type [`JacocoReport`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport.html) (which is defined by the `jacoco` plugin?). This task will collect the execution data produced by the test runner into a report and therefore depends on a task for actually running the tests.
3. Configure the task(s) with the correct locations of source, target, execution files, etc.
4. Add any additional JaCoCo customizations.

As mentioned in the question, the Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) already includes JaCoCo support. This means that we don't need to explicitly enable the [`jacoco`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html) plugin. It [looks like the used version can be configured](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171125857#comment15) using

```
android {
    jacoco {
        version = "..."
    }
}
```

[This blog post](https://medium.com/@gmazzo65/generating-android-jvm-aggregated-coverage-reports-53e912b2e63c) discusses various shortcomings on AGP's JaCoCo support and proposes a Gradle plugin (in Kotlin) to address them.

## 1. Enable coverage instrumentation

AGP supports this directly by setting [`enableUnitTestCoverage`](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.4/com/android/build/api/dsl/BuildType#enableUnitTestCoverage()) on the appropriate build type:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        debug {
            ...
            enableUnitTestCoverage true
        }
    }
```

There also is the [`testCoverageEnabled`](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.4/com/android/build/api/dsl/BuildType#isTestCoverageEnabled()) (deprecated combination of `enableUnitTestCoverage` and `enableAndroidTestCoverage`) option which additionally creates tasks that we can't use when running in CI without an actual device as described in the question.

## 2. Create Gradle task

Gradle tasks are defined with the `tasks.create` method. A task has a name, a type, and a set of other tasks that it depends on. In this case this means something like

```
tasks.create(name: "unitTestCoverageReport", type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "testLocalDebugUnitTest") {
   // ... task implementation ...
}
```

where `testLocalDebugUnitTest` is an existing task that runs the unit tests with coverage collection enabled. Use `./gradlew tasks | grep -i test` to list all available tasks related to testing.

The task can be defined in the `gradle.build` file of the module that needs it (what I did), or it can be defined in a separate file to be applied from the toplevel module as in @fah's answer or imported explicitly as in some of the posts listed below.

By virtue of this being written in a full programming language, there are many possibilities for setting up abstractions around this construct in whatever way makes sense for the project at hand:

- [This example](https://thsaravana.github.io/blog/jacoco-single-coverage-for-multi-module/) shows how JaCoCo may be integrated into a monorepo-like project, i.e. a project with multiple Gradle modules. It defines a generic JaCoCo Gradle module that can be imported into the individual `build.gradle` files to add a `debugCoverage` task for each of them (assuming that they have a variant "debug"). It then adds a dummy module `jacoco` with a single task `allDebugCoverage` that collects the coverage data produced by `debugCoverage` from all the other modules (assuming that they have been run first). The [JaCoCo Report Aggregation Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_report_aggregation_plugin.html) looks like a possible alternative solution.
- [This example](https://medium.com/jamf-engineering/android-kotlin-code-coverage-with-jacoco-sonar-and-gradle-plugin-6-x-3933ed503a6e) creates a task for each variant.
- [This example](https://github.com/rameshkec85/UnitTestCaseDemo/blob/master/flavored_jacoco.gradle) creates it for each flavor.

With the task `unitTestCoverageReport` being defined, it may be run using `./gradlew unitTestCoverageReport`. Dependent tasks will be automatically be executed (transitively) first.

## 3. Configure Gradle task

As mentioned above, the task implementation sets up the configuration of JaCoCo report generator. As also seen in @Fah's answer, the relevant fields are:

- `reports`: block for configuring which kinds of reports to generate.
- `sourceDirectories.from`: The location of the original source code files. Optional, but allows the reporter to map bytecode instructions back to the original sources in order to include them into the report with coverage annotations.
- `classDirectories.from`: The compiled class files *without* instrumentation. Execution data references instructions in these classes, so they're necessary for locating the actual instructions.
- `executionData.from`: The location of "execution data", i.e. the coverage data collected by the unit test runner when running the tests against classes instrumented by the JaCoCo agent.

So while one just has to set these paths correctly, this can be challenging when the build process is poorly documented and you don't have good understanding of the underlying structure. In my case it involved a combination of guessing, searching the build directory for files with specific extensions, and reading other examples. I have for example not found any official documentation explaining that compiled Kotlin classes go into `${buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes`.

Despite being named "directories", all guides I've seen pass the entire directory tree using the [`fileTree`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileTree.html) function with a bunch of `exclude`s. For my Kotlin Android project, the following configuration suffices:

```
tasks.create(name: "unitTestCoverageReport", type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "testLocalDebugUnitTest") {
    group = "Verification" // existing group containing tasks for generating linting reports etc.
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports for the 'local' debug build."

    reports {
        // human readable (written into './build/reports/jacoco/unitTestCoverageReport/html')
        html.enabled = true
        // CI-readable (written into './build/reports/jacoco/unitTestCoverageReport/unitTestCoverageReport.xml')
        xml.enabled = true
    }

    // Execution data generated when running the tests against classes instrumented by the JaCoCo agent.
    // This is enabled with 'enableUnitTestCoverage' in the 'debug' build type.
    executionData.from = "${project.buildDir}/outputs/unit_test_code_coverage/localDebugUnitTest/testLocalDebugUnitTest.exec"

    // Compiled Kotlin class files are written into build-variant-specific subdirectories of 'build/tmp/kotlin-classes'.
    classDirectories.from = "${project.buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes/localDebug"

    // To produce an accurate report, the bytecode is mapped back to the original source code.
    sourceDirectories.from = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"
}
```

I think the XML report is mostly useful for further processing like uploading the report to [coveralls](https://github.com/kt3k/coveralls-gradle-plugin#use-with-jacoco-plugin).

Some guides wrap the task definition in `project.afterEvaluate`. I didn't find a need for this and don't know enough about Gradle to understand what difference it makes.

## 4. Additional JaCoCo customizations

To collect coverage data for tests executed by for example [`RobolectricTestRunner`](https://robolectric.org/), the following snippet must be added as well:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses true
    jacoco.excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']
}
```

[This post](https://about.codecov.io/blog/code-coverage-for-android-development-using-kotlin-jacoco-github-actions-and-codecov/) suggests using the `testOptions` block to set configurations like these.

Finally, the `jacoco` plugin also includes a configuration [`jacocoTestCoverageVerification`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html#sec:jacoco_report_violation_rules) for failing the build if certain coverage metrics aren't met.

## GitHub Actions

The following example workflow runs the Gradle task and uploads the generated HTML report as a workflow artifact using [`madrapps/jacoco-report`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/jacoco-report):

```yaml
name: Build and test with coverage
on: ...
env:
  java_version: "17"
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up JDK
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: "${{env.java_version}}"
          distribution: temurin
          cache: gradle # caches dependencies (https://github.com/actions/setup-java#caching-packages-dependencies)
      - name: Build project and run unit tests
        run: ./gradlew test unitTestCoverageReport --no-daemon
      - name: Add coverage comment to PR
        uses: madrapps/jacoco-report@v1.3
        with:
          paths: "${{github.workspace}}/app/build/reports/jacoco/unitTestCoverageReport/unitTestCoverageReport.xml"
          token: "${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}"
      - name: Store HTML coverage report
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: coverage-report
          path: "${{github.workspace}}/app/build/reports/jacoco/unitTestCoverageReport/html/"
```

Answer (score 2):

## I made jacoco work like this:

1. Create jacoco.gradle file in the top level of your project:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.8"
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses true
    jacoco.excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']
}

task jacocoUnitTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest']) {
    reports {
        csv.enabled false
        xml {
            enabled true
        }
        html {
            enabled true
        }
    }

    // Add files that should not be listed in the report (e.g. generated Files from dagger)
    def fileFilter = ['**/*Dagger.*']

    def kotlinDebugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)

    def mainSrc = "$projectDir/src/main/java"
    sourceDirectories.from = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories.from = files([kotlinDebugTree])
    
    // Make sure the path is correct (if not run the unit tests and try find the .exec file that is generated after the unit tests are finished should be similar to that one)
    executionData.from = fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", includes: ["outputs/unit_test_code_coverage/debugUnitTest/testDebugUnitTest.exec"])
}
```

2. Add this to your top level project build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.8.8"
    }
    subprojects {
        afterEvaluate { project ->
            project.apply from: '../jacoco.gradle'
        }
    }
```

3. Add `testCoverageEnabled = true` to your build type in the apps build.gradle
4. Run `./gradlew jacocoUnitTestReport` in your terminal
5. Find the report in /app/build/reports/jacoco/jacocoUnitTestReport

Comment: When I migrated to AGP 8.0 Jacoco giving 0 coverage. Any idea where will be the issue

Comment: @Rameshbabu same for me. Did you manage to find the issue?

Comment: @user1122549 For me the issue is different now. I have a total of 4 modules including the app. Getting coverage for 3 modules and not for the app.